# Grep non-inline-comment lines without -v option

Tags: grep

I want to grep all none `#` comment lines,

Although I can use `grep -v -E '^\s*#'`, I want to know if there is another way not using -v(revert) option.

```
    #a comment line from a tab
     abcd
xx
#a comment line from head
 #a comment line from a space
```

I tried many patterns but failed:

```
grep -E '^\s*[^#]'
grep -E '^[ \t]*[^#]'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ grep -E '^\s*[^#[:space:]]' hashfile 
     abcd
xx
```

#### Discussion

Since a space is not `#`, the regex `^\s*[^#]` will any line that begins with zero or more spaces followed by one space.

We could have used a blank and tab explicitly if we wanted:

```
$ grep -E '^\s*[^# \t]' hashfile 
     abcd
xx
```

#### Compatibility

`\s` is a GNU extension to `grep`.  In extended regular expressions (`-E`), `[:space:]` is the character class containing white space characters.  For a portable solution, use:

```
$ grep -E '^[[:space:]]*[^#[:space:]]' hashfile 
     abcd
xx
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a question existing long time ago. Sometimes grep does not work as js regexp, it seems \s* or '^[[:space:]]*' is not aggressively matched as expected.